# if statement is true but doesnt go into the block

Tags: coffeescript

This is my coffe script:

```
jQuery ->
if $('#infinite-scrolling').size() > 0 
  $(window).on 'scroll', ->
    window_top = $(window).scrollTop()
    doc_height = $(document).height()
    window_height = $(window).height()
    window_bottom = window_top + window_height
    scroll = window_bottom / doc_height > 0.9 
    next_page = $('.next_page').attr('href')
    console.log(next_page)
    console.log($('#infinite-scrolling').size() > 0)
    if next_page && scroll
      $.getScript next_page
    return
return
```

It doesnt get into the `if` block allthough the statement in the `if` should be `true` because when I remove the `if` then I can see in the console that its `true` through this line:

```
console.log($('#infinite-scrolling').size() > 0)
```

Anyone any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which if block is failing?
Please include your HTML so we know what `#infinite-scrolling` and `.next_page` are.

Comment: hey thanks to try to help me. I stated that the first if is not getting triggered allthough the clause should be true. I just made this in javascript because I dont know why coffee script is running wrong and it works now

Answer (score 0):

The if statement looks fine. 
The code works for me once I fix the indentation, except that `.size()` is deprecated in the latest jquery (3.3.1). I replaced it with `.length`. 
But I can't test the second if block without your HTML.

Are you sure there are no errors thrown?

Here is my version:

```
jQuery ->
  if $('#infinite-scrolling').length > 0 
    $(window).on 'scroll', ->
      window_top = $(window).scrollTop()
      doc_height = $(document).height()
      window_height = $(window).height()
      window_bottom = window_top + window_height
      scroll = window_bottom / doc_height > 0.9 
      next_page = $('.next_page').attr('href')
      console.log(next_page)
      console.log($('#infinite-scrolling').length > 0)
      if next_page && scroll
        $.getScript next_page
      return
return
```

And here as a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QVRjpO)

Comment: yeah I dont know why it didnt work either, I have just switched to plain old JS, I need my `;`'s and `{}`'s